# Is this ER Diagram correct?

Tags: relational-database, entity-relationship

I am attempting to create an Entity-Relationship Diagram which satisfies the following requirements:

> • Each customer has a name, a permanent address, and a social security
>   number.
>
> • Each customer can have multiple phone numbers, and the same
>   phone number may be shared by multiple customers.
>
> • A customer can
>   own multiple accounts, but each account is owned by a single customer.
>   • Each account has an account number, a type (such as saving,
>   checking, etc.), and a balance
>
> • The bank issues an account statement
>   for each account and mails it to its account owner every month. As
>   time goes on, there will be multiple statements of the same account.
>
> • Each statement has an issued date and a statement ID.  All the
>   statements of the same account have different statement IDs, but two
>   different accounts could have statements with the same statement ID. 
>   For example, it is possible that account A has a statement with ID
>   ‘123', while account B has another statement with the same ID '123'.

I have implemented this:

[image]

I have a few questions:

1. Can Min-Max notation be used in case of any relationships, or, just when there is an indication for that in the description?
2. Are my many-to-many relationships portrayed correctly here?
3. Could I properly portray the relationships among Account vs Account Statement vs StatementID?
4. As per my assumption, Is Account Statement really a weak entity and is `Has` really a weak relation that is dependent on Statement ID? Is issue-date a weak key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1. 
Yes. they can be used in case of any relationships. If description lacks that info, it does not mean that info does not exist.

Q2 and Q3 and Q4.
`Phone Number` should be a multi-valued attribute instead of entity. 
`Statement Id` should be weak key of `Account Statement` instead of being an entity. when you make the above changes, you will realize that `Account Statement` depends on `Account` as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

1. This notation is a bit odd to me, as I'm used to place the numbers near the edge on which they apply (is not the same having a 1-N relationship than a N-1 one). Personally, I like to always indicate the cardinality in the relationships.
2. I have the following comments:

   - A customer can own more than one account, so the cardinality of the relationship is (1, N).
   - An account can generate more than one account statement, so the relationship is (1, N).
3. I think you can have the statement ID as an attribute of AccountStatement (and as a "weak key"), and use the Account number as the other component for the compound key (as I see it, AccountStatement has a compound key, composed by the statement ID and the account number).
4. I think that AccountStatement is in fact a weak entity. In the context of what I said in 3, I would not consider issue date as a key (although maybe the account number and the issue date could be a compound candidate key), and I would remove the Has relationship and the StatementID entity, moving the statement ID to an attribute of AccountStatement.

Hope it helps!